# regex: match lines that don't match sub-regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I have a regex expression *foobar* and I want to find all lines in a document that contain no match to *foobar*.  Can I do this?  How do I do this?

Comment: some people may suggest you print out the line when there is no match, but i think your question is, what is a regex that is a "match" when there is no such word

Comment: Correct! - And I didn't know you could use kanji in a user name!  Cool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
^(?!.*foobar.*).+$
```

With multiline option, matches all line that does not contain foobar..

Comment: This looks about right to me... but it's not working if I try it here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: it is nonsense, but when I checked extended checkbox, it has worked.. Try with RAD regular Expression Designer

Answer (score 0):

The regexp
for your case can be this

```
^((?!foobar))$
```

edited:

but if you only want grep something you can use -v parameter:

```
grep -v foobar
```

Comment: That matches any line that doesn't start with foobar.  I need to match any line that does not *contain* foobar.

Comment: Do you need this to grep tool?

Comment: You could have at least leave a note that you have changed your answer as now some comments may be irrelevant.

Comment: @MPekalski, nice idea - I'll do this